# How to use `androidx.compose.material3.DatePicker`to only allow the user to pick months and years

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use the [Datepicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#DatePicker(androidx.compose.material3.DatePickerState,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.DatePickerFormatter,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.material3.DatePickerColors)) to allow the user to only select the month and year. The user should not be allowed to see the day. The day is irrelevant.

If possible. Also provide a Datepicker that allows the user to select a day, but not month and year. The month and day will be provided by the system. So if it's February of a leap year. They should have the selection of 29 days instead of 28.

Comment: AFAIK, `DatePicker` does not handle those scenarios. Your second scenario is just a `NumberPicker`. For the first, you may need to look at third-party libraries.